# ¿Por qué el operador "is" no funciona para comparar valores?

Tags: python, python-3.7, operador

Estuve usando el operador `is` en python para comparar valores idénticos, mas realizando un ejercicio resulta que no responde como esperaba.

Ejemplo 1

```py
a = 1
b = 1
print(a is b)
True
```

Ejemplo 2

```py
a = 1000
b = 1000
print(a is b)
False
```

No entiendo la razón de que los ejemplos respondan diferente si en ambos casos los valores son iguales.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hay muchas cosas muy interesantes que comentar en esta pregunta. Vamos por partes:

## Nunca usar `is` para comparar valores

El operador `is` tiene un cometido muy específico y es ver si dos variables "apuntan" al mismo objeto. Para comprender esto ayuda conocer un poco cómo es el modelo de datos de Python.

Si conoces C, te diría que *todo en Python son punteros a objetos*. Si no conoces C, baste decir que cada variable Python no es una "caja" en la que metas un valor, sino que es un "apuntador" que señala a un objeto, que es quien en verdad tiene el valor (y un tipo). Por eso la variable en sí no tiene tipo, sino el dato al que "apunta".

Esto también vale para enteros. Por tanto cuando haces:

```
a = 1000
```

El intérprete python crea un objeto de tipo `int`, guarda en ese objeto el valor `1000`, y hace que el identificador `a` "señale" a ese objeto. Sería la situación siguiente:

[image: a]

Si después haces

```
b = a
```

Entonces se crea un nuevo identificador `b` que *apuntará al mismo dato que `a`*, pues eso es lo que ocurre cuando asignas una variable a otra (esto es aplicable también a listas, cadenas, o cualquier otro tipo, e incluso si `b` es el argumento de una función a la que pasas `a` como parámetro). La situación ahora será:

[image: a y b]

En este momento `a` y `b` se refieren al mismo objeto. Por tanto `a is b` será `True` ya que para esto es para lo que sirve el operador `is`, para ver si ambos se refieren al mismo objeto. El operador `==` en cambio compara *los objetos*. Naturalmente `a == b` también será  `True` si `a` y `b` se refieren al mismo objeto.

### Un inciso: inmutabilidad y reasignación

Quizás te estés preguntando *"Esto no puede ser así, pues si ahora cambio el valor de `b` haciendo por ejemplo `b = b + 1` también cambiará el de `a`, ¿no?"*

Resulta que no, porque un entero es *inmutable*, que significa que no lo puedes cambiar por otro. El número 1000 es el número 1000, y nunca podrá convertirse en el número `1001`.

*¡Un momento!* estarás pensando. ¿Cómo que no? ¿qué ocurre entonces si hago...

```
b = b + 1
```

Lo que ocurre es bastante sorprendente. El intérprete Python tendrá que evaluar el lado derecho de la asignación, para lo cual creará otro entero con valor 1, y lo sumará al entero "señalado" por `b`, que como vimos es 1000. El resultado de esa suma sale 1001, y por tanto Python **creará un nuevo dato** para el resultado, con valor 1001, y **reasignará** la variable `b` para que apunte a este nuevo dato. El 1000 original no se ha modificado (no podría, pues es inmutable). La cosa queda por tanto así tras la línea anterior:

[image: b+1]

Naturalmente ahora ya es falso que `a == b` y también que `a is b` pues apuntan a objetos diferentes.

## Entonces, volviendo a tu pregunta

Esto explica el segundo caso en tu pregunta:

```
a = 1000
b = 1000
print(a is b)    # Sale False
```

ya que estas asignaciones dan lugar a la figura siguiente:

[image: a = 1000, b = 1000]

Donde podemos ver claramente que apuntan a objetos separados, y por tanto `a is b` es falso, pero esos objetos tienen el mismo valor y por tanto `a == b` es verdadero.

Ahora bien **¿Qué está pasando aquí?**

```
a = 1
b = 1
print(a is b)    # Sale True (¿¿¿???)
```

¿no debería ser este caso igual al anterior?

Pues **resulta que no**. De forma casi inexplicable, las líneas anteriores dan lugar a la siguiente figura:

[image: a=1 b=1]

Viendo la figura queda claro que `a is b` es verdadero, pero ¿por qué el 1 se comporta diferente al 1000?

Este es un detalle de optimización del intérprete CPython. Resulta que este intérprete, para mejorar sus prestaciones, tiene ya *creados de antemano* los enteros entre -5 y 256, ambos inclusive [[referencia](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html)], porque estos enteros se usan muy a menudo. Cuando una variable en tu programa es asignada a uno de estos enteros, se le hace apuntar al dato pre-creado. Por eso al final `a` y `b` apuntan "al mismo 1". Y en realidad todas las variables de tu programa que valgan 1, apuntarán "al mismo 1".

De todas formas, esta es una característica en la que no deberías basarte a la hora de escribir los programas. El hecho de que para esos enteros en particular (y también para algunas cadenas) el `is` funcione, no deja de ser un "accidente". Nunca te bases en esto.

> En definitiva, usa `is` cuando quieras mirar si dos valores "señalan" al mismo dato, y usa `==` cuando quieras comparar si los datos señalados son iguales.

Comment: Buena explicación, aunque en mi opinión la respuesta está en los últimos 3 parrafos. ¿Tienes la fuente que menciona la optimización de CPython?

Comment: @gustavovelascoh He añadido la referencia a la respuesta, y de paso corregido que los números pre-creados empiezan en -5 y no en 0.

Comment: ¡Excelente explicación! Si bien la respuesta está en la frase "Nunca usar is para comparar valores", el soporte posterior a la frase aporta mucho valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación ahora me quedo claro @abulafia

Comment: Fantástica respuesta, qué interesante el descubrimiento de que CPython optimiza entre -5 y 256.

Answer (score 3):

El operador `is` no compara que dos valores sean idénticos, sino que compara a donde apuntan cada uno de ellos.

Si utilizas la funcion `id(a)` e `id(b)` verás el objeto al que apuntan.