# Duda sobre variable dinamica lista y punteros en python

Tags: python, lista

Estoy estudiando del sgte pdf: http://editorial.uader.edu.ar/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Algoritmos%20y%20estructuras%20de%20datos%20en%20Python%20-%20digital.pdf en la pagina 69 ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) dice así:

> "Las operaciones útiles de comparaciones que se puede hacer entre punteros son dos, si ambas variables son iguales –es decir si están apuntando a la  misma variable dinámica– o si los punteros son distintos –si no están apuntando a la misma variable dinámica–. Esto se puede ver en la figura 3, la salida del programa será para el primer caso “Apuntan a diferentes variable dinámica” y “Apuntan a la misma variable dinámica” para el segundo caso".

Hago la practica y no me da el mismo resultado, me retorna en los dos casos que los punteros apuntan a la misma variable dinamica, por lo que estoy muy confundido con el tema de las variables apuntando a objetos dinamicos.

```
def punteros_iguales(p1, p2):
    if(p1 == p2): #si esta comparacion fuera entre los id me parecería logico el resultado señalado por el libro que además en la practica no concuerda
        print("apuntan a la misma variable dinamica") 
    else:
        print("apuntan a diferentes variable dinamica")

puntero1=[0,1]
puntero2=[0,1]
punteros_iguales(puntero1, puntero2) #apuntan a la misma variable dinamica (deberia ser distinta segun el libro)
puntero2={}
puntero1=puntero2
punteros_iguales(puntero1, puntero2) #apuntan a la misma variable dinamica
```

Answer (score 0):

La definición de *puntero* como tal no existe en python, eso es propio de otros lenguajes como C, C++, etc. Aunque internamente python si trabaje con ellos lo que más encontrarás serán *referencias*.

El problema principal es que el operador `==` se utiliza para comparar los valores (contenido de las variables u objetos), no para comparar si una variable *apunta* a otra. Si quieres saber si una variable hace referencia a otra se utiliza la palabra `is` La cual compara las referencias de las variables, si ambas variables se refieren al mismo objeto almacenado en memoria entonces retorna `True` pero si el objeto no tiene referencia a otra variable retorna `false`.

Con tu código quedaría así:

```py
def punteros_iguales(p1, p2):
    if(p1 is p2): #si esta comparacion fuera entre los id me parecería logico el resultado señalado por el libro que además en la practica no concuerda
        print("apuntan a la misma variable dinamica") 
    else:
        print("apuntan a diferentes variable dinamica")

puntero1=[0,1]
puntero2=[0,1]
punteros_iguales(puntero1, puntero2) #apuntan a la misma variable dinamica (deberia ser distinta segun el libro)

puntero2={}
puntero1=puntero2
punteros_iguales(puntero1, puntero2) #apuntan a la misma variable dinamica
```

Dando como resultado

```
apuntan a diferentes variable dinamica
apuntan a la misma variable dinamica
```

Esto sucede por que en el primer caso se están creando 2 variables, por lo que cada una se guarda en lugares distintos de memoria, pero en el segundo caso solo se crea una variable `{}` pero luego a la variable `puntero2` le asignamos la referencia de la variable `puntero1` por lo que podemos decir que `puntero1` y `puntero2` *apuntan* al mismo objeto.

En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306705/183782) se tiene el escenario contrario al tuyo, donde se utiliza `is` para comparar valores (el contenido de la variables), léelo y aprenderás mucho :D.