# Como encontrar la ventana que desencadeno un evento en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una función `callback` con el evento  de cierre: `self.toplevel_1.bind ('<Destroy>', lambda: self.close_windows (3))` , pero  `Destroy`se aplica a todos los widgets descendientes de `Toplevel` por lo que en la función vinculada tengo que encontrar a Toplevel para solo referirla a ella y no a los demas widget descendientes, leí que deberia usar  `event.widget` pero no se como deberia implementarlo . Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

```
from tkinter import *

class A (Frame):
    def __init__(self,master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self._open_1 = False
        self._open_2 = False
        self.btn = Button(self, text='create winoows', command= self.create)
        self.btn .pack()

    def create(self):
        if self._open_1 is False:
            self.w1 = Toplevel(self.master)
            self.w1 .title('window 1')
            self.w1 .bind('<Destroy>',lambda f: self.close_windows(1))
        
        if self._open_2 is False:
            self.w2 = Toplevel(self.master)
            self.w2 .title('window 2')
            self.w2 .bind('<Destroy>',lambda f: self.close_windows(2))

        self._open_1 = True
        self._open_2 = True

    def close_windows(self,  number, event=None):
        if number is 1:
            event.widget.destroy()
            self._open_1 = False

        if number is 2: pass #......

root = Tk()
a = A(root)
a .pack()
root .mainloop()
```

Cabe resaltar que `'WM_DELETE_WINDOW'` no entraría al caso porque la ventana no tiene el gestor de ventanas.

Comment: Hola, no es suficiente con hacer ```event.widget.destroy()```? O necesitas el padre del widget?  Creo que necesita más contexto la pregunta..

Comment: @DannyTalent Te agradezco la sugerencia pero es como tu dices necesito al padre porque ```<destroy>```  destruye todos los widget descendientes.

Comment: entonces podrías usar ```event.widget.master.destroy()``` si lo que quieres es destruir el parent

Comment: @DannyTalent Acabo de actualizar el código añadiendo tu sugerencia al script, también lo he modificado de tal manera que puedas reproducir el código, espero puedas ayudarme te lo agradecería un montón.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy del todo seguro de qué pretendes, pero el problema está en que el parámetro `event` de tu callback nunca es asignado en la invocación, y por tanto tiene el valor `None` que le das por defecto.

La razón de eso está aquí:

```
self.w1.bind('<Destroy>', lambda f: self.close_windows(1))
```

La función `bind` espera dos parámetros. El primero es el evento y el segundo es una función que, cuando sea invocada por tk, recibirá como parámetro un evento. En tu caso esa función es la `lambda` y el parámetro que recibe (al que has llamado `f`) sería el evento en cuestión. Pero como ves no estás usando `f` para nada. Basta pasárselo como segundo parámetro a `close_windows()`.

Reescribiendo entonces esa línea (y aprovechando para cambiar `f` por un nombre más significativo) quedaría así:

```
self.w1.bind('<Destroy>', lambda event: self.close_windows(1, event))
```

### Código completo

El código completo quedaría como sigue. He aprovechado también para cambiar tus `if number is 1`  por `if number == 1`, y el `if self._open_1 is False` por `if not self._open_1`, que es lo correcto (mira [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/306662/7123) para saber por qué no debe usarse `is` para comparaciones).

```
from tkinter import *

class A (Frame):
    def __init__(self,master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self._open_1 = False
        self._open_2 = False
        self.btn = Button(self, text='create winoows', command= self.create)
        self.btn.pack()

    def create(self):
        if not self._open_1:
            self.w1 = Toplevel(self.master)
            self.w1.title('window 1')
            self.w1.bind('<Destroy>', lambda event: self.close_windows(1, event))
        
        if not self._open_2:
            self.w2 = Toplevel(self.master)
            self.w2.title('window 2')
            self.w2.bind('<Destroy>', lambda event: self.close_windows(2, event))

        self._open_1 = True
        self._open_2 = True

    def close_windows(self, number, event=None):
        if number == 1:
            self._open_1 = False
            event.widget.destroy()
            print("DEBUG: Close 1", event)

        if number == 2: 
           self._open_2 = False
           event.widget.destroy()
           print("DEBUG: Close 2", event)

root = Tk()
a = A(root)
a.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

## Bonus

El código se puede refactorizar para que use listas de ventanas y de booleanos, en lugar de las variables `_open_1`, `_open_2`, `w1`, `w2`. De este modo es más generalizable y fácilmente puedes hacer que se creeen y manejen cualquier número de ventanas.

Esta sería la versión con listas:

```py
from tkinter import Toplevel
from tkinter import *

class A (Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, nwindows=2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.master = master

        # Preparamos la lista de booleanos y la de windows
        self._open = [False] * nwindows
        self.windows = [None] * nwindows

        self.btn = Button(self, text='create windows', command= self.create)
        self.btn.pack()

    def create(self):
        # Crear mediante un bucle las ventanas que no estén creadas
        for i in range(len(self._open)):
            if not self._open[i]:
                w = Toplevel(self.master, width=300)
                w.title(f'window {i+1}')
                w.bind('<Destroy>', 
                        lambda event, number=i: self.close_windows(number, event))
                # Actualizar las listas
                self.windows[i] = w
                self._open[i] = True

    def close_windows(self, number, event=None):
        # Como medida de seguridad, aunque esto no debería ocurrir
        # verifico si la ventana ya estaba cerrada
        if not self._open[number]:
            return
        # La cierro y actualizo la lista
        self._open[number] = False
        event.widget.destroy()
        print(f"DEBUG: Close {number}")

root = Tk()
a = A(root, nwindows=4)  # Probamos con 4 ventanas
a.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Observa que en esta implementación no necesitarías usar `event.widget` para cerrar la ventana correcta. Podrías hacer `self.windows[number].destroy()`.

Comment: Gracias por las lecciones y por tu tiempo, tu sugerencia resolvió mi problema, tomaré tu consejo de la listas de boleanos, muchas gracias

Comment: Me di una pasada al enlace de la pregunta que me dejaste , y reproduje el ejemplo 2 de la pregunta hecha por el autor de ella, con un resultado True contrario al resultado obtenido por el autor de la pregunta. A que se debe este cambio en los resultados?

Comment: El resultado es diferente si lo ejecutas directamente en el intérprete (en el prompt `>>>`) que si lo escribes en un script y lo ejecutas. Eso se debe a que el script es "compilado" en una primera pasada que tiene oportunidad de hacer algunas optimizaciones que el intérprete interactivo no puede hacer, en concreto reutilizar el mismo objeto de valor 1000 una vez ha sido creado en la primera asignación. De todas formas creo que tu comentario y este mío estarían mejor en la otra pregunta.