# Orden alfabético y menor numero de caracteres Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estaba realizando un código donde se debe introducir por teclado el nombre y los apellidos de 3 personas con el siguiente formato: Apellido1, Apellido2 dichos datos
deberán aparecer ordenados alfabéticamente por apellidos. En caso de
igualdad de apellidos aparecerá primero aquel cuyo nombre tenga menor
número de caracteres.
Como harían para mostrar aquellos apellidos que presentan una igualdad?

```
Vector = list()
print("Persona 1:")
Apellido1 = str(input("Ingrese su apellido: "))
print("Persona 2:")
Apellido2 = str(input("Ingrese su apellido: "))
print("Persona 3:")
Apellido3 = str(input("Ingrese su apellido: "))

Vector.append(Apellido1)
Vector.append(Apellido2)
Vector.append(Apellido3)

for recorrido in range(1,len(Vector)):
    for posicion in range (len(Vector) - recorrido):
        if Vector[posicion] > Vector [posicion + 1]:
            temp = Vector[posicion]
            Vector[posicion] = Vector[posicion + 1]
            Vector[posicion + 1] = temp


print(Vector)
```

no me dejan usar las funciones definidas en python, tengo que crear cada una y eso reeemplaza al sorted(), tendria que ordenarlos segun su longitud pero sin una funcion que haga lo mismo que el sort()

Comment: Hola bienvenido a stack overflow en español te invito a que completes el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas obtener tu primer medalla. Con respecto a tu pregunta no me queda muy claro si solo debes de introducir un apellido por persona o dos.

Comment: La respuesta más simple usaría `sort()` y su parámetro `key` pero ya que se trata de un ejercicio es posible que no se permita el uso de esa función (o que aún no la conozcas). Se te está pidiendo que implementes tu propia función de ordenación?

Comment: Si los apellidos son iguales, ¿cómo pueden tener distinto largo?

Comment: @CandidMoe yo tampoco entiendo eso. Lo podría comprar si fuese un fuzzy search en plan González/Gonzálezz pero eso sería más complejo...Que lo aclare el OP

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ordenar primero alfabéticamente y luego por longitud:

```
Vector = list()
print("Persona 1:")
Apellido1 = str(input("Ingrese su apellido: "))
print("Persona 2:")
Apellido2 = str(input("Ingrese su apellido: "))
print("Persona 3:")
Apellido3 = str(input("Ingrese su apellido: "))

Vector.append(Apellido1)
Vector.append(Apellido2)
Vector.append(Apellido3)

Vector.sort()
print(Vector)

Vector.sort(key=lambda s: len(s))
print(Vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede resumir un poco con un for en repetición de pregunta: y buena práctica ceñirse al pep-8 con las mayúsculas. Un saludo

```
vector = list()
for i in range(1,4):
  print(f'Persona {i}:')
  apellido= input("Ingrese su su primer apellido y separado por una ',' el segundo apellido")
  vector.append(apellido)
vector.sort(key=lambda s: len(s))
vector=sorted(vector)

print(vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar una lista sin usar `sort` lo más simple es hacer un *bubble sort*. La única complicación aquí es el criterio de ordenamiento:

- Primero por apellido, y
- A igual apellido, por largo del nombre.

La solución es crear un nuevo item de datos que combine:

- Una llave compuesta de apellido (en minúsculas) + largo del nombre.
- El *input* original del usuario.

Esta es el código que ingresa la información:

```
TAMANO = 3
lista = []
for i in range(TAMANO):
     persona = input(f"Ingrese 'Apellido, Nombre' de persona {i+1}: ")
     apellido, nombre = persona.split(",")
     largo = len(nombre)
     lista.append(f"{apellido.lower()}{largo:02} - {persona}")
```

Primero se pide el "apellido, nombre" como una sola línea y se separa usando `split`. Con eso, y el largo del nombre, la expresión

```
f"{apellido.lower()}{largo:02} - {persona}"
```

genera un elemento del tipo

```
'soto05 - Soto, Juan'
```

La ventaja de este método es que si dos personas coinciden en el apellido y tienen nombres del mismo largo, serán ordenados alfabéticamente por apellido+nombre, como debe ser.

Ahora que hemos simplificado el tema de la llave, implementamos *bubble sort*

```
for i in range(TAMANO - 1):
    for j in range(i, TAMANO):
        if lista[i] > lista[j]:
            lista[i], lista[j] = lista[j], lista[i]
```

Finalmente, tomamos la lista ordenada y producimos una salida limpia, con sólo el *input* original, usando comprensión de listas

```
final = [x.split(" - ")[-1] for x in lista]
```

#### Demo

```
TAMANO = 3
lista = []
for i in range(TAMANO):
     persona = input(f"Ingrese 'Apellido, Nombre' de persona {i+1}: ")
     apellido, nombre = persona.split(",")
     largo = len(nombre)
     lista.append(f"{apellido.lower()}{largo:02} - {persona}")

for i in range(TAMANO - 1):
    for j in range(i, TAMANO):
        if lista[i] > lista[j]:
            lista[i], lista[j] = lista[j], lista[i]

final = [x.split(" - ")[-1] for x in lista]
print(final)
```

produce:

```
Ingrese 'Apellido, Nombre' de persona 1: Soto, Alejandro
Ingrese 'Apellido, Nombre' de persona 2: Soto, Alvaro
Ingrese 'Apellido, Nombre' de persona 3: Soto, Juan
['Soto, Juan', 'Soto, Alvaro', 'Soto, Alejandro']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

No es una respuesta que buscas pero sí quizás la que necesitas. Esto es más una protesta pasivo-agresiva ante lo que me parece un ejemplo "antipedagógico " y contraproductivo. Me parece que enseñar Python prohibiendo lo que realmente lo hace especial es un error y que para enseñar algoritmos de ordenación existen otras formas.

### Sé que las respuestas de opinion no son aceptadas en el sitio pero espero que se me perdone de forma excepcional.

Este código es simple, conciso y utiliza únicamente las funciones built-in de python; aquí declaras vector como una lista vacía y pides cuantos apellidos quieres introducir y los añades a la lista (no hace falta convertir a `str` la salida de input porque `input()` ya devuelve una cadena.)

```
vector = []
indice = int(input("Cuantos Apellidos?: "))
    
for i in range(indice):
    vector.append(input(f"Apellido {i+1}: "))
```

Después usas el método `sort()` de la lista `vector` y ordenas alfabéticamente con `lower()` y de menor a mayor con `len()` (puedes usar varias claves de ordenación a la vez)

```
vector.sort(key=lambda v: (v.lower(), len(v)))
```

Después saneas un poco comprobando si hay repetidos con la función `set()` (que acepta la lista y devuelve una tupla solo con valores únicos) y si el set y el vector son de igual tamaño significa que no hay duplicados y si el set es más pequeño entonces hay duplicados, itera sobre `vector` usando el método `count()` por cada apellido del set (recuerda que el set son únicos) y te imprime los apellidos duplicados y cuantas veces.

```
if len(set(vector)) != len(vector):
    for apellido in set(vector):
        cuenta = vector.count(apellido)
        if cuenta > 1:
            print(f'Apellido "{apellido}" está repetido ({cuenta} veces)')
else:
    print("No hay apellidos repetidos")
```

Output:

```
Cuantos Apellidos?: 5

Apellido 1: Almeida
Apellido 2: Ayuso
Apellido 3: Fraga
Apellido 4: Rajoy
Apellido 5: Fraga

['Almeida', 'Ayuso', 'Fraga', 'Fraga', 'Rajoy']

Apellido "Fraga" está repetido (2 veces)
```

Espero que esta respuesta te dé una nueva perspectiva de las capacidades de Python cuando lo usas de la forma en la que está diseñado y te ayude a escribir mejor código y más eficiente.

Comment: No veo casi nada malo en tu respuesta, sin embargo, [nunca uses is para comparar valores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306705/158880)

Comment: Lo sé. Suelo usar != pero lo que me gusta de Python es su similitud con el lenguaje humano y me pareció que “is not” era más explícito.

Comment: Puede ser mas explicito, pero si leiste la respuesta de Abulafia, te darás cuenta de que is not y != NO hacen lo mismo. Así que te recomiendo tener cuidado.

Comment: Conseguí crear un ejemplo donde dos numeros iguales dan false al ser comparados con is. Ejecuta este código y verás: `a = len("1"*1000)
b = len("2"*1000)

print(a, b)
print(a == b)
print(a is b)`

Comment: Editado. Gracias por el apunte.

Comment: Es un placer c:

Comment: @DanteS. Recuerda que puedes usar el punto y coma `;` para separar las expresiones. Eso simplifica las cosas al copiar y pegar código en 1 sola línea  ;)

Comment: Gracias @Christian! Lo tendré en cuenta la proxima.

Comment: Por cierto te puedes ahorrar varias líneas is usas una comprensión de lista  `vector = [input(f"Apellido {i+1}: ") for i in range(int(input("Cuantos Apellidos?: ")))]`

Comment: Si utilizas el módulo `collection` también te puedes ahorrar otras cuantas líneas

Comment: @Christian ya tío, pero tampoco quería ahorrarme líneas a costa de hacerlo menos “beginner friendly” xD