# Cuando usar is o == Python

Tags: python

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy tomando un curso de python, y al momento de hacer una función para saber que valor devolver, la persona del curso hacía este `if`:

```
if value is None:
  return ""

return value
```

Y entonces me pregunto ¿hay alguna diferencia importante entre hacer eso a hacer un?:

```
if value == Null:
  return ""

return value
```

Desde ya gracias :).

Comment: Si tienes que comparar contra un `Null`, no uses ninguna de las 2 formas; en esa condición Python interpreta `Null` como `(bool) False`. Así que usa simplemente: `if value:`, o a la inversa, `if not value` (como en tu caso).

Comment: @aeportugal y si estoy haciendo una función y quiero diferenciar None de una tupla vacía, como hago con tu forma? Ambos dan False.

Comment: Además, Null no existe en Python (a menos que declares una variable llamada así). No quisiste decir None?

Comment: @DanteS. lo siento si, era None, mi error, ya edité la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

`is` devolverá Verdadero si las variables apuntan al mismo objeto y `==` si los objetos a los que se refieren las variables son iguales.

```
  >>> 1000 is 10**3
  False
  >>> 1000 == 10**3
  True
```

Comment: cerca, lee [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/306662/183782)

Comment: lo resumi xd @Christian

Comment: Mmm... pues quedan muchas cosas en el aire, editaría tu respuesta agregando todo pero no vale la pena, la pregunta será cerrada por duplicada y todo se perderá :/

Answer (score -2):

Si no me equivoco el `==` es para hacer una comparación y el `is` es para saber si existe dentro de un conjunto.

[Mas info...](https://pywombat.com/articles/diferencia_is_doble_equals_python)

Comment: nop, equivocado!

Comment: Confundiste is con in.

Comment: Si es verdad, mala mia