# Importar datos de un fichero .txt a multiples variables en Python

Tags: python

estoy intentando hacer que mi programa saque datos de un archivo .txt para cargarlos en multiples variables como son name, mark, mail y phone, pero como no entiendo mucho de programación no se si estoy haciendo correctamente el código y cuando ejecuto lo que he implementado, me da un error de "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object", a lo cual intuyo que el código que he usado no es el correcto o que no se solucionar el error.
El archivo .txt viene dado así:

```
Juan González Torres,7,juan@micorreo.es,654321987
María González Torres,9.5,maria@mail.com,958999999
Juan José Bustos García,4,jj@micorreo.es,958654321
María José Sánchez Moreno,2.7,mj123@mail.com,63521636
Mario López Vargas,5,mario0@mymail.com,612345678
```

Y el código del programa viene dividido en 2 archivos .py:

-Éste sería students.py:

```
from marks import (
    store_student_data,
    show_student_list,
    average,
    filter_students_above,
    search,
)


MARK_PASSED = 5


INPUT_STUDENT_DATA = '1'
SHOW_STUDENT_LIST = '2'
CALCULATE_AVG = '3'
GET_NUMBER_PASSED = '4'
SHOW_STUDENTS_ABOVE_AVG = '5'
SEARCH_STUDENT = '6'
EXIT_PROGRAM = '7'

MENU_OPTIONS = (
    '1 - Añadir datos de estudiantes',
    '2 - Mostrar lista de estudiantes',
    '3 - Calcular calificación media',
    '4 - Calcular número de aprobados',
    '5 - Listar estudiantes con nota superior a la media',
    '6 - Buscar estudiantes',
    '7 - SALIR DEL PROGRAMA'
)

def show_menu():
    print('\nOpciones:')
    for option in MENU_OPTIONS:
        print(option)

def get_student_data():
    print('\n¿Desea cargar la información de los alumnos de otro archivo?')
    print('Y/N')
    answer = input().lower
    if answer() == 'Y' :
        with open('ampliacion gestion academica/students.txt', 'r') as myfile:
            for linea in myfile.readlines():
                name = str(linea).split(",")
                mark = str(linea).split(",")
                mail = str(linea).split(",")
                phone = str(linea).split(",")
    elif answer() == 'N' :
        print('\nPor favor, introduzca los datos\n')
        name = input('Nombre del alumno: ')
        mark = input('Nota del alumno: ')
        mail = input('Introduce el mail del alumno: ')
        phone = input('Introduce el número de teléfono del alumno: ')
        return name, float(mark), mail, phone


def process(option, student_list):
    if option is INPUT_STUDENT_DATA:
        name, mark, mail, phone = get_student_data()
        store_student_data(name, mark, mail, phone, student_list)
    elif option is SHOW_STUDENT_LIST:
        show_student_list(student_list)
    elif option is CALCULATE_AVG:
        avg = average(student_list)
        if avg is None:
            print('\nNo hay datos. Por favor introduzca valores.')
        else:
            print(f'\nResultado de la media: {avg}')
    elif option is GET_NUMBER_PASSED:
        students_passed = filter_students_above(student_list, MARK_PASSED)
        number_passed = len(students_passed)
        print('\nNúmero de aprobados: ' + str(number_passed))
    elif option is SHOW_STUDENTS_ABOVE_AVG:
        avg = average(student_list)
        students_above_avg = filter_students_above(student_list, avg)
        show_student_list(students_above_avg)
    elif option is SEARCH_STUDENT:
        text = input('\nIntroduzca parte del nombre a buscar: ')
        students_matching = search(student_list, text)
        show_student_list(students_matching)


students = []
user_option = None
while user_option != EXIT_PROGRAM:
    process(user_option, students)
    show_menu()
    user_option = input('\nPor favor, seleccione una opción: ')
```

-Éste sería marks.py:

```
import mailbox
import pickle

def store_student_data(name, mark, mail, phone, student_list):
    student = {}
    student['name'] = name
    student['mark'] = mark
    student['mail'] = mail
    student['phone'] = phone

    student_list.append(student)


def show_student_list(student_list):
    print('\nLista de estudiantes:')
    for student in student_list:
        print('\nNombre : ' + student['name'])
        print('Calificación : ' + str(student['mark']))
        print('Mail : ' + str(student['mail']))
        print('Teléfono : ' + str(student['phone']))


def average(student_list):
    if len(student_list) == 0:
        return None
    total_sum = 0
    for student in student_list:
        total_sum += student['mark']
    return total_sum / len(student_list)


def filter_students_above(student_list, threshold):
    result = []
    for student in student_list:
        if student['mark'] >= threshold:
            result.append(student)
    return result


def search(student_list, text):
    result = []
    text = text.lower()
    for student in student_list:
        if text in student['name'].lower():
            result.append(student)
    return result
```

Comment: Si la opción elegida por el usuario es `1` y luego `y`, la función `get_student_data` del primer script no devuelve nada, por lo tanto la función retorna None, y como None no es iterable, no se puede desempacar. Además, [nunca uses is para hacer comparaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306705/158880)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que split() regresa una lista. [split](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split)

Answer (score 2):

Es posible que el error se encuentre en la función `get_student_data()`, pues `linea` tiene el valor de un string correspondiente a cada linea leída del fichero txt. El `método split` lo que hace es tomar esa línea y crear una lista formada por las cadenas que surgen al usar el separador ','. Por lo que primero deberás tomar la linea usando `split` como lo haces y guardarlo en una lista, y ya posteriormente podrás asignar los valores en `name, mark, mail y phone` accediendo a cada posición de esa lista, sería algo así:

```
with open('ampliacion gestion academica/students.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for linea in myfile.readlines():
        lista = linea.split(',')
        name, mark, mail, phone = lista[0], lista[1], lista[2], lista[3]
```

Comment: También puedes usar mejor el unpacking y hacer `name, mark, mail, phone = lista` asumiendo que lista siempre tendrá 4 items.