# Python re.findall para buscar dentro de una lista

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy comenzando con expresiones regulares y tengo una lista llamada **models** donde tengo guardados modelos de coches. Lo que quiero es guardar los modelos que contienen un número en el nombre. Estoy probando cosas como estas pero solo consigo guardar los números y no el nombre del modelo.

```
y = [re.findall(r"[0-9]",m) for m in models]
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme!

ejemplo:

models = [a, b1, c1, c, b, b2, 11as, 222, abc, cba, 1b2]

salida  = [b1, c1, b2, 11as, 222, 1b2]
Es decir, solo los que contengan números

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionar una muestra de tus datos de entrada y de los resultados que quieres obtener?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solución sin usar expresiones regulares

Si lo que buscas saber es si la cadena tiene al menos un numero, no necesitas expresiones regulares:

###### Código

```
models =  ['a', 'b1', 'c1', 'c', 'b', 'b2', '11as', '222', 'abc', 'cba', '1b2']
    
salida = [model for model in models if(any(char.isdecimal() for char in model))]

print(salida)
```

###### Produce

```
['b1', 'c1', 'b2', '11as', '222', '1b2']
```

###### Explicación

Colocando un if a la derecha de la comprensión de lista, le decimos que solo agregue a la lista los resultados que cumplen cierta condición.

La función [any](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#any) recorre un iterable (lista, tupla, cadena, etc) o iterador (generador, etc) hasta que algún item devuelva True (en ese caso any devuelve True). Si nada dió True, devuelve False.

Lo que está dentro de los parentesis se llama comprensión de generador. Cuando a una comprensión se la encierra entre parentesis, devuelve un objeto generador. Este objeto (a diferencia de la comprensión de lista) va generando los datos conforme son necesarios.

any es equivalente a:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

El método [isdecimal](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) de las cadenas nos dice si la cadena está conformada por numeros.

Esto significa que el código `any(char.isdecimal() for char in model)` recorrerá la cadena model caracter por caracter hasta que encuentre un caracter que sea un numero.

#### Pero si insistes...

El problema puede ser resuelto usando expresiones regulares:

###### Código

```
import re

models =  ['a', 'b1', 'c1', 'c', 'b', 'b2', '11as', '222', 'abc', 'cba', '1b2']
    
salida = [model for model in models if(re.search("\d", model) is not None)]

print(salida)
```

###### Produce

```
['b1', 'c1', 'b2', '11as', '222', '1b2']
```

###### Explicación

Colocando un if a la derecha de la comprensión de lista, le decimos que solo agregue a la lista los resultados que cumplen cierta condición.

La función [re.search](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.search) devuelve la primera coincidencia del regex en la cadena. En este caso el regex es `\d`, que significa "coincidí con un numero".
Si no se encontró coincidencia alguna, devuelve None. En este caso usamos is para saber si lo que se devolvio **es** el objeto None. Este es un caso especial, pero generalmente [no uses is para hacer comparaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306705/158880)

Answer (score 0):

La expresión regular que buscas es:

```
"(.+) (\S*\d\S*)"
```

Usemos este dato para probar, donde "Aston Martin" es la marca y "DB3" el modelo.

```
Aston Martin DB3
```

La expresión regular tiene dos partes: la primera `(.+)` intenta consumir toda la línea hasta encontrar un espacio seguido del resto, que será reconocido por la segunda parte. Al poner entre paréntesis, la *capturamos*, es decir, el texto reconocido queda guardado y luego lo podemos recuperar.

La segunda parte es `(\S*\d\S*)`, que reconoce cualquier cosa que tenga un dígito. Puedo o no tener otras letras, dígitos o simbolos, antes o después. Estos son consumidos por la subexpresión `\S*`, que significa *cero o más ocurrencias de cualquier cosa que no sea espacio*. Aquí capturamos el modelo.

Si una línea es reconocida por esta expresión, obtendremos una tupla:

```
('Aston Martin', 'DB5')
```

de la cual podemos extraer marca y modelo.

El método `findall` devuelve un lista. Si el texto calza, su primer elemento contiene la tupla (marca, modelo).

#### Demo

```
import re

models = [
"Honda Integra",
"Audi A3",
"BWM M3",
"Subaru XV",
"Fiat 125",
"Aston Martin DB3"
]

patron = re.compile(r"(.+) (\S*\d\S*)")
for model in models:
    m = patron.findall(model)
    if m:
        marca, modelo = m[0]
        print(f"Marca: {marca}, modelo: {modelo}")
```

produce:

```
Marca: Audi, modelo: A3
Marca: BWM, modelo: M3
Marca: Fiat, modelo: 125
Marca: Aston Martin, modelo: DB3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Nope, findall no devuelve un match object, si no una lista.

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias. Corregido