# Menu para introducir y validar fechas

Tags: python-3.x

Deseo crear un script que me solicite dos fechas y , si el formato es el adecuado, las almacene en dos variables predefinidas.

Esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

def validar_fecha(test_str):
    # inicializar el formato
    format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    # Comprobar si el formato es el adecuado
    res = True
    # Aplicamos try-except para verificar el fromato
    try:
        res = bool(datetime.strptime(test_str, format))
    except ValueError:
        res = False
    return res

def seleccionar_fecha():
    try:
        start = input("\nIntroduzca la fecha de inicio (YYYY-M-D: \n")
        res = validar_fecha(start)
        if res == False:
            seleccionar_fecha()
            
        opcion = input("\nEs la fecha final el día de hoy s/n:\n")
        if opcion == "s":
            end = dt. datetime.now()
            #end = date.today()
        else:
            end = input("\nIntroduzca la fecha de finalización (YYYY-M-D: \n")
        res = validar_fecha(end)
        if res == False:
            seleccionar_fecha()
            
    except ValueError as err:
        print('Error, introduzca un numero valido')
        seleccionar_fecha()


seleccionar_fecha()
```

Funciona correctamente, pero me parece excesivamente complicado, por depender de dos funciones.
¿Alguna idea de cómo podría conseguir lo mismo de forma más sencilla?. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: El código tiene errores de sintaxis. Edita la pregunta y corrigelos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simplificación

No tiene nada de malo que tu código dependa de dos funciones. Sin embargo, si es cierto que se puede simplificar:

1. En la función validar_fecha, podemos devolver la versión convertida de la fecha si es que tuvo éxito, y si no devolver None. Esto nos evitará convertir la fecha más adelante.
2. No es necesario inicializar tantas variables en validar_fecha. Por ejemplo el formato puede pasarse directamente antes de primero declarar una variable que lo referencie. Debido al punto anterior, ya no es necesario inicializar la variable res.
3. Los cambios en la función validar_fecha (la cual ahora se encargará de devolver la fecha o None si la conversión falla) nos llevará a cambiar un poco el código de nuestra función principal, para que cuando lo guardado en las variables start y end sea None, el código vuelva a empezar.
4. No necesitamos el try-except en la función principal. En ningún momento ingresas un numero y las validaciones necesarias las haces con la función validar_fecha.

#### Código resultante

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

def validar_fecha(test_str):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(test_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        return

def seleccionar_fecha():
    start = validar_fecha(input("\nIntroduzca la fecha de inicio (YYYY-M-D: \n"))

    if(start is None):
        seleccionar_fecha()
        
    opcion = input("\nEs la fecha final el día de hoy s/n:\n")
    if opcion == "s":
        end = dt.datetime.now()
        #end = date.today()
    else:
        end = validar_fecha(input("\nIntroduzca la fecha de finalización (YYYY-M-D: \n"))
    if end is None:
        seleccionar_fecha()


seleccionar_fecha()
```

Nota: En este caso uso is para saber si lo devuelto por validar_fecha **es** None, pero este es un caso especial. En general [nunca uses is para hacer comparaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306705/158880).

#### Bonus: Algunas observaciones a tu código

No soy experto en buenas practicas, pero aun así considero los siguientes puntos parte de buenas costumbres a la hora de programar.

###### Cuidado con el try-except

Cuando envuelves un bloque de código en un try-except, estás capturando errores. Eso significa que podrías tener errores confusos a la hora del desarrollo. Toma este código de ejemplo:

```
a = input("ingrese un numero: ")

try:
    b = int(input("numero1"))
    
    if(int(a) == b):
        print("los numeros no pueden ser iguales")

except ValueError:
    print("Numero no valido.")
```

Imagina que el usuario ingresa en a, en lugar de un número, una palabra. A la hora de probar la condición `if(int(a) == b):` sucederá un ValueError, no por que el numero ingresado en b sea invalido, si no por que no se pudo convertir a  a en numero. Esto produce:

```
ingrese un numero: hola
numero11
Numero no valido.
```

Entonces aparecerás aquí con una pregunta diciendo "Estoy ingresando un número valido y mi código dice que no es valido".
Cuando estas cosas pasan, siempre hay que sospechar del try-except antes de tirar la toalla y preguntar aqui.

Pero estos errores se pueden evitar casi en lo absoluto. Simplemente trata de tener la menor cantidad de código posible dentro del try. Cuanto menos código, mejor, así reducirás las posibilidades de que ocurran estos extraños errores.

En nuestro código de ejemplo, no parece haber necesidad de que el if esté dentro del try:

```
a = input("ingrese un numero: ")

try:
    b = int(input("numero1"))
except ValueError:
    print("Numero no valido.")

if(int(a) == b):
    print("los numeros no pueden ser iguales")
```

Produce:

```
ingrese un numero: hola
numero11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[censurado]\Desktop\mis funciones.py", line 45, in <module>
    if(int(a) == b):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hola'
```

Como podrás ver, el error ahora es mucho más claro.

###### Evita en lo posible el uso de funciones recursivas.

Usar [funciones recursivas](https://entrenamiento-python-basico.readthedocs.io/es/latest/leccion5/funciones_recursivas.html) en lugar de un bucle es una mala idea ya que:

- Suelen ser confusas (al menos para mi)
- Existe un limite de recursión. Eso significa que si el usuario falla más veces que el limite de recursión, tu código dará un error.

Solución, usa un bucle:

```
while True:
    start = validar_fecha(input("\nIntroduzca la fecha de inicio (YYYY-M-D: \n"))

    if(start is None):
        # el continue significa "No ejecutes el código de abajo y vuelve al principio del bucle"
        continue

    opcion = input("\nEs la fecha final el día de hoy s/n:\n")
    if opcion == "s":
        end = dt.datetime.now()
        #end = date.today()
    else:
        end = validar_fecha(input("\nIntroduzca la fecha de finalización (YYYY-M-D: \n"))
    if end is None:
        continue

    # esto detiene el bucle a la fuerza.
    break
```

###### Comodidad para el usuario

Tu programa puede ser un poco pesado (perdón si ofendo, no es la intención) para el usuario. Imagina que ingresa la fecha final mal. Tal como está tu código el usuario tendría que ingresar la fecha inicial nuevamente, a pesar de haber estado bien ingresada.

Solución: usa un bucle por dato ingresado. De ese modo, si algo falla podrás hacer que el código retroceda un paso en lugar de, por ejemplo, 10.

Más abajo pondré un código que implementa estos puntos.

#### Código con las observaciones anteriores aplicadas

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

def validar_fecha(test_str):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(test_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        return

def seleccionar_fecha():
    while True:
        start = validar_fecha(input("\nIntroduzca la fecha de inicio (YYYY-M-D: \n"))

        if(start is not None):
            break

    opcion = input("\nEs la fecha final el día de hoy s/n:\n")
    if opcion == "s":
        end = dt.datetime.now()
        #end = date.today()
    else:
        while True:
            end = validar_fecha(input("\nIntroduzca la fecha de finalización (YYYY-M-D: \n"))

            if end is not None:
                break


seleccionar_fecha()
```

Comment: Completa y pedagógica ayuda. Efectivamente, yo era consciente de que me faltaba por resolver  cómo volver atrás un paso, sin iniciar de nuevo todo el proceso, cuando el fallo está, por ejemplo, en la introducción de la fecha final. La solución que apuntas, usar un bucle por dato ingresado, es perfecta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Algo poco conocido por mi  y por tanto, que no me viene automáticamente a la mente como opción cuando programo, son los bucles con while. De ahora en adelante, tendré muy presente evitar en lo posible el uso de funciones recursivas.

Comment: Asimismo, veo que tengo pendiente estudiar un poco más acerca de las posibles excepciones que se pueden devolver en los bucles try - except..

Comment: De nada :D Suerte con este camino de aprender a programar nwn