# ¿Cómo reemplazar el error que genera int cuando se ingresa un dato de tipo string en Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

```
option = int(input("Elige una opción: 1 para suma. 2 para restar. 3 para multiplicar. 4. para dividir: "))

if option == 1:
    print("SUMA")
    valor1 = int(input("Dame el valor1: "))
    valor2 = int(input("Dame el segundo valor: "))
    resultado = valor1 + valor2
    print("El resultado de tu suma es",resultado)

elif option == 2:
    print("RESTA")
    valor1 = int(input("Dame el valor1: "))
    valor2 = int(input("Dame el segundo valor: "))
    resultado = valor1 - valor2
    print("El resultado de tu resta es",resultado)

elif option == 3:
    print("MULTIPLICACIÓN")
    valor1 = int(input("Dame el valor1: "))
    valor2 = int(input("Dame el segundo valor: "))
    resultado = valor1 * valor2
    print("El resultado de tu multiplicación es",resultado)
    
elif option == 4:
    print("DIVISIÓN")
    valor1 = int(input("Dame el valor1: "))
    valor2 = int(input("Dame el segundo valor: "))
    resultado = valor1 / valor2
    print("El resultado de tu division es",resultado)

else:
    print("Solo puedes elejir una opción del 1 al 4.")
print("Fin.")
```

Yo se que int se usa para ingresar datos numéricos pero, me gustaría cambiar el error de int por un print, con un mensaje pero, no se si eso se pueda hacer.

**ERROR de int**

Traceback (most recent call last):
line 1, in 
option = int(input("Elige una opción: 1 para suma. 2 para restar. 3 para multiplicar. 4. para dividir: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'

**Lo que busco hacer**

Remplazar ese error, ese mensaje por un print o que no muestre ese mensaje y simplemente se saliera.

Comment: Usa un [try-except](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). De hecho, el ejemplo de la documentación es casi lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
try:

  option = int(input("Elige una opción: 1 para suma. 2 para restar. 3 para multiplicar. 4. para dividir: "))

except:

  print("Ingresa un dato válido")
```

Comment: Dos cosas. Primero, te recomiendo dar una explicación de lo que hace el código. Stack Oveflow no es un repositorio de código y con una explicación el OP podría aprender algo nuevo. Además, en lo personal, no me parece buena idea capturar cualquier error. Solo el error generado especificamente por la función int cuando no puede convertir una cadena en entero (ValueError).

Comment: ¡Gracias! todo OK

Comment: OK pero podrias decirme porque no es buena idea capturar cualquier error? Cómo capturo el error ValuError?

Comment: Por que puede ocurrir un error que no esperas. Esta respuesta tiene más información, leé la parte que está titulada como "bonus" y luego busca el subtitulo "cuidado con el try-except": https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/522789/158880. Sobre tu segunda duda, revisa el link que te dejé hacia la documentación. Ahí tenés un ejemplo de uso que justamente captura solamente el ValueError.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo quieres que haga un except ValueError

Comment: Exactamente. Cuanto menos excepciones de más captures mejor, cuanto menos código en el try, mejor también. Si no será más probable que captures un error inesperado y te termine apareciendo el mensaje que le programaste para cierto escenario.

Comment: OK Entiendo, muchas gracias.