# ¿Por qué en Python el Operador de identidad IS devuelve TRUE al evaluar 2 variables diferentes con valores enteros superiores a 256 en VSCode?

Tags: python, vscode, punteros, operador

Según entendí gracias a esta explicación:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306705/290691

el intérprete CPython, para mejorar sus prestaciones, tiene creados previamente los valores enteros hasta 256, haciendo que al asignar uno de estos valores a una variable en realidad apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria sin importar si este valor lo tiene diferentes variables. Con lo cual al evaluar con el operador de identidad dos variables distintas que apunten a un valor entero menor o igual a 256
devolvería TRUE a pesar de ser objetos distintos, resultando en una ejecución mas óptima del programa. (Nota: Es una mala práctica en Python evaluar igualdad con operadores de identidad). Sin embargo haciendo pruebas en mi computadora esto aplica desde la consola de Python. Pero si lo ejecuto desde Visual Studio Code siempre arroja TRUE al evaluar diferentes variables con el mismo valor entero incluso por encima de 256. No le encuentro explicación a esto.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El comportamiento es ligeramente diferente si ejecutas Python en modo interactivo (es decir, para obtener el prompt `>>>`) que si lo ejecutas sobre un programa previamente escrito en un fichero (un script).

Cuando estás en modo interactivo, Python no sabe lo que vas a hacer a continuación, por lo que no aplica el mismo tipo de optimizaciones que cuando le das un script para ejecutar. En este segundo caso, Python hace un primer parseado del fichero completo, para verificar que no contenga errores de sintaxis (básicamente indentación incorrecta o ausencia de dos puntos tras ciertas líneas, etc.). Durante ese "procesamiento inicial" convierte todo tu código fuente a *opcodes* (códigos binarios para la "máquina virtual python" por así decir). Es ese código binario (y no el fuente python) el que finalmente ejecutará el intérprete.

Durante esa "compilación", python puede aplicar optimizaciones adicionales al tener todo el código "a la vista". Una de esas optimizaciones consiste en reciclar los enteros y los datos inmutables. Ya que un entero es inmutable (no le puedes cambiar de valor), tiene sentido que si detecta que estás asignando a dos variables diferentes un mismo número, ese número lo cree en memoria una sola vez y asigne a esas variables una referencia al mismo número, razón por la que después `is` devolverá `True`.

Como dije antes esta optimización no la hace en modo interactivo, en la que sólo aplica la optimización de tener pre-creados los enteros entre -5 y 256 por ser los más comunmente utilizados.

### Ampliación

Por otro lado, considera el siguiente código:

```py
a = 123123
b = 123123
print(a is b)  # True

c = 123000
for i in range(123):
  c+=1
print(a == c)  # True
print(a is c)  # False
```

En este caso el primer `print()` muestra `True`, pues como se ha explicado antes Python puede detectar que el número 123123 se ha usado dos veces en este código, por lo que asigna tanto `a` como `b` una referencia al mismo objeto de tipo entero.

Sin embargo el último `print()` mostrará `False` a pesar de que `c` al final vale también 123123. Eso se debe a que en este caso Python no puede "deducir" el valor final de `c` sin ejecutar el código. Y la ejecución no ocurre hasta que todo el código ha sido ya compilado y convertido a *bytecode*. Así que el "compilador" no puede aplicar esta optimización en ese caso.