# ¿Por qué un método recursivo en Python no toma el valor por defecto de un parámetro en segundas llamadas, sino que conserva su valor previo?

Tags: python

Dada una clase que genera objetos con una referencia a otro objeto de la misma clase (como por ejemplo, una lista enlazada), quiero crear un método recursivo que devuelva una lista con los datos contenidos en una serie de objetos encadenados.
Una versión simplificada de lo que quiero hacer sería la siguiente:

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, num: int, next: "Nodo"=None):
        self.num = num
        self.next = next

    def get_list(self, l=list()):
        l.append(self.num)
        if self.next:
            return self.next.get_list(l)
        else:
            return l
        
a = Nodo(4)
b = Nodo(3, a)
c = Nodo(2, b)
d = Nodo(1, c)

print(d.get_list())
print(d.get_list())
```

Cada vez que invoco al método `Nodo.get_list()` no paso ningún argumento asociado al parámetro "l", y por tanto, espero que el mismo sea inicializado como una lista vacía. Sin embargo, la salida de este código es la siguiente:

> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Es decir, la segunda llamada conserva memoria de la lista devuelta en la primera, y sobre ella agrega los nuevos elementos.
Quiero comprender este comportamiento y conseguir que el valor del parámetro "l" se reinicialice en cada llamada al método.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema se encuentra cuando defines la función, justo aquí:

```
def get_list(self, l=list())
```

Los defaults en Python se crean una sola vez y luego se guardan en memoria para usarse cada vez que sea necesario.
Esto significa que la lista NO se crea en cada ejecución, si no que se reutiliza.

Cuando haces append, modificas la lista default, no una nueva lista.

La solución a este problema es, teniendo una variable x, usar un default constante (comunmente None) y, si el valor de x ES el valor default, asignarle a x una lista vacía.

```
def hola(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = []

    ...
```

Esto funciona ya que, a diferencia de los defaults, el código dentro de la función se ejecuta en su totalidad cada vez que es llamada (excepto casos muy especificos, pero que no te van a afectar). Las listas creadas dentro del cuerpo de la función siempre se crean en cada ejecución.

NOTA: generalmente, no hay que usar is para comparaciones de igualdad. None es un caso especial en el que es conveniente usar is. Si querés más información, mira esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306705/158880

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, Dante! Muy clarificadora la respuesta. Me sugiere otra pregunta: ¿cree que sería eficiente y seguro usar objetos mutables como defaults de funciones para conservar valores de una llamada a otra, al estilo de las variables "static" de C?

Comment: De nada c: No entiendo el ejemplo de C por que no conozco el lenguaje, pero, y doy mi opinión, dependiendo el propoposito y, especialmente, si vas a modificar dicho objeto, podría ser más optimizado en velocidad, ya que el objeto se crea una sola vez (ten en cuenta el gasto de memoria, siempre busca un equilibrio). En el caso particular que señalaste en tu pregunta, no creo que la mejora en velocidad si funcionase bien sea mucha. De todas formas, si querés usar el mismo objeto para varias ejecuciones, te conviene más atributos de clase y, rara vez, variables globales.

Comment: Énfasis en que el problema está en usar el default en la cabecera de la función **y luego modificar dicha variable**. Si se crease una nueva lista en vez de modificarla, no habría problema. Ejemplo: dejando la cabecera de la función igual que en la pregunta (esto es, `def get_list(self, l = list()):`), si se cambiase el cuerpo por la siguiente línea, se obtendría siempre el resultado esperado: `return self.next.get_list(l + [self.num]) if self.next else l + [self.num]`. Muy buena respuesta Dante.

Comment: Gracias Jabro! Es cierto lo que dices, pero concatenar listas no es muy optimizado. Y mantener el default como una lista simplemente podría llevar a comportamientos confusos y una "limitación" en la funcionalidad. La mejor opción, en mi opinión, es la tecnica del None.

Comment: Sin duda. Tu propuesta es más eficiente en memoria y, salvo que alguien me corrija, la "best practise". La mía era solo un ejemplo para complementar la respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces buen complemento!